# How to solve the problem in login json parsing using volley?

Tags: android, json

```
    public void userLogin() {
        try {
            String URL = "http://influence360.in/orezmiapp/index.php/mobile/login";
            System.out.println("Arun URL :- " + URL);
            final JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("type", "2");
            jsonBody.put("email", email);
            jsonBody.put("password", password);

            final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            Log.e("JSON String is :- ", " " + mRequestBody);

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("LOG_VOLLEY", response);


                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "loginactivity entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        int status = jsonObject.getInt("status");
                        Toast.makeText(activity, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (status == 1000) {
                            JSONObject data = jsonBody.getJSONObject("data");
                            //sessionManager.setUserid(data.getString("Cust_id"));
                            // sessionManager.setBirthday(data.getString("Dob"));
                            sessionManager.setUserfirstname(data.getString("Cust_Name"));
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginScreen.this, Profile.class));
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener()

            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("LOG_VOLLEY", error.toString());
                }
            })

            {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    String responseString = "";
                    if (response != null) {

                        responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);

                        Log.e("Response String : -", " " + responseString);

                    }
                    return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new

                    DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        }
```

I got the error 
value of type 200 org.json.Integer cant be converted into JSONObject. Please help me to solve this. I didnt get any solution regarding this. Thankyou in advance.Please help me out.I will be highly obliged if anybody give the solution.Thank you in advance. If anybody has the solution please give me that.

Comment: which line of code get this error? what is the result?

Comment: JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(response); this line get error

Comment: upload your log

Comment: Add your josn data. and your logcat error

Comment: this is my json response:

Comment: {"status":1000,"data":{"Cust_Id":"2060","Dob":"14 Jan, 1986","Cust_MobNo":"9643236614","Cust_UserName":"seorahulchauhan","Cust_Email":"seorahulchauhan@gmail.com","wallet_balance":120,"talktime_balance":119,"SMS_balance":19,"Cust_Status":0,"Cust_Name":"Rahul Chauhan","Cust_State":"Delhi","Cust_Nationality":"Indian","Cust_Religion":"Hindu"},"message":"success.","custom":{}}